# SOAP to REST and REST to SOAP mediation in Fuse ESB

Tags: rest, soap, apache-camel, fuseesb

I have a requirement where I would be receiving SOAP calls and have to mediate it to rest calls to invoke some services using fuse ESB. Is there any facility in Fuse to achieve this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html should give most of what is required. There are many posts on SO, search for "camel soap proxy".

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly straight forward. I just posted an example of exposing some GitHub REST api calls as SOAP calls here http://code.notsoclever.cc/camel-soap-rest-bridge-example/

I used a processor and HTTPUrlConnection to make the REST calls but you could also use the CXFRS or Restlet components to make the REST calls.